# Unarchiving a .tar file in ios 8

Tags: ios, swift

How would I untar a file in iOS 8?

I have followed these examples: *NVHTarGzip, Light-Untar, ZipArchive* however I have not been able to make them work.

Comment: NVHTarGzip this works for some file. but i tested for english and hindi file, it did not work. Can any one help if "tesseract-ocr-3.02.hin.tar.gz" working or not. If download through code and unzip it through code. If i simply download unzip it and zip it again manually. I getting no error while unzipping this manually zipped file.

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: @vik it extracts upto nearly 50% then gives error. the message written by programmer.

Comment: Yes, but the error message is important to understand what's the exact issue

Comment: The error message was written like this, "some error occurred please try after some time." but every time it fails to unzip. now I store all the files in to my server. on click the language I downloading  it from my server.

Comment: Where is the code you used?

Comment: It appears `tesseract-ocr-3.02.hin.tar.gz` has a bad file descriptor; If you manually untar the file and tar -cf the extracted contents chances are it will work just fine.

Comment: @I'L"I exactly I have exactly done that at last. And now I am storing it on my local server. Now I am downloading as per the language selected by user and unzip the .tar.gz file. I had solved the problem like this. +1 for you hint.

Answer (score 1):

For my team, we used Light-Untar-for-iOS available at 
 https://github.com/mhausherr/Light-Untar-for-iOS

The actual line of code where we do it is:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("es_ES", ofType:"tar") {
        let documentDirectory:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = documentDirectory[0] as! String
        var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var isDirectory: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(true)
        if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(documentDirectoryPath + "/\(toLocale)", isDirectory: &isDirectory){
            fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(documentDirectoryPath + "/\(toLocale)", withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error)
        }
        var destinationPath = documentDirectoryPath + "/\(toLocale)"
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFilesAndDirectoriesAtPath(destinationPath, withTarPath: path, error: &error, progress: { (progress) -> Void in
            println("Progress \(progress)")
            self.tarTimer?.invalidate()
            self.tarTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "untarDone:", userInfo: [fromLocale, toLocale], repeats: false)
        })
    }
```

Comment: How would you do this in swift if NSfileManager was removed and is now FileManager. I can't use the method: createFilesAndDirectoriesAtPath :(

Comment: @humbleCoder That's a Light Untar method. You need to have Light Untar for iOS as a dependency.